# Swift 4, How do I put a lot of library photos to uiscrollview?

Tags: uiscrollview, swift4

I'm making a photo library app. 
I am using the collectionView for the images to layout and when i get a touch on the cell i am going to a another uiscrollview. 
and for the scroll view i am append image like this.

```
for i in 0...imageArray.count {
   (add image to scrollview)
}
```

and allow the user to use swipe gesture to get the next or the back photo from the library. 
but this problem is that when the array has over 1000 photos inside of it. it takes a lot of time to load. Is there a better way doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can only seed your scrollview with the tapped image, the previous image of the tapped index, and next image of the tapped index. Ex, if 5th image is tapped, then feed scrollview with only 4,5 and 6. When user swipes to next and sees 6 image, then feed your scrollview with only 5,6 and 7. I imagined that user can only swipe to left or right and shows only one picture on the screen.